# DDD: Referencing non-roots. Alternative?

Tags: c#, oop, domain-driven-design

I'm currently working on an application, where `Facilities` with `Facility Items` and `Assessments` with `Findings` are managed (this is a mobile app with a windows management app and I'm only describing a small part of it).

Currently it is implemented very CRUD with an anemic model and I would like to apply some ideas from DDD to make my model richer/robust and enforce some invariants.

The new requirement I like to implement is to get information about the facility items/findings by scanning a `Tag` attached to them.

[image: Simplified Model]

The `Team` owns a predefined set of tags. Currently these are some qr codes printed on magnetic labels, but of course nfc tags could be used as well.
While a team member performs an assessment, whenever he identifies a finding, he sticks a tag on the 'target' and scans it. Later other team members can scan the existing tag and get information about the finding. If a finding is no longer relevant, the tag might be reused for other findings.

These are my (simple) requirements:

- A tag can be assigned either to a facility or a finding.
- If a tag is reassigned, the old assignment is no longer active.
- It is possible to query the facility item/finding using the tag.

The simple/obvious solution is to reference the tag directly from the finding/facility item. But I think this has some drawbacks:

1. It might be necessary to change two ARs in one transaction, e.g. if the tag was previously used for a finding and is now used for a facility item
2. I think a facility item must not know anything about a tag. It's not really a property of it, is it?
3. I'm using Optimistic Locking and changing an 'assignment' would also change the finding/facility item and the owning AR. I guess this might lead to concurrency issues.

I thought I could use some kind of a 'Tag Assignment' Entity with references to the tag and to the facility item/finding instead. With this solution I could easily change the assignment. Does this make sense?
But there is at least one problem with this solution: The reference to the facility item/finding from the tag is 'not allowed' in DDD (because only ARs should be referenced).

I wonder how someone would model this with DDD? Any thoughts? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> I thought I could use some kind of a 'Tag Assignment' Entity with references to the tag and to the facility item/finding instead. With this solution I could easily change the assignment. Does this make sense? But there is at least one problem with this solution: The reference to the facility item/finding from the tag is 'not allowed' in DDD (because only ARs should be referenced).
>
> I wonder how someone would model this with DDD? Any thoughts?

The problem you describe has one feature which is critical to understand as you design your solution: *the model is not the book of record*.

> Currently these are some qr codes printed on magnetic labels, but of course nfc tags could be used as well. While a team member performs an assessment, whenever he identifies a finding, he sticks a tag on the 'target' and scans it

Notice that these activities are taking place in the real world; your domain model doesn't get a veto.

A second thing to notice is that while a `Tag` may be an entity in the real world, you don't actually care.  Your scanner bounces light off of the tag, analyzes the reflection, infers a QR code, and sends a representation of that QR Code along.  (The picture of your model already suggests that you understand this).

> If a finding is no longer relevant, the tag might be reused for other findings.

This sounds like your model needs to understand *time*.  People in the real world want to be able to tell your model "As of {date:...}, Tag{qrcode:...} has been assigned to Finding{id:...}"

> The Team owns a predefined set of tags.

You need to think hard about what ownership really means in your design.  There isn't anything in the problem description that suggests that a Team AR is responsible for maintaining a business invariant about the state of tag.  If a Team were reorganized out of existence, would all of its Tags "go away"?  Probably not.

My guess is that ownership is more like assignment "As of {date:...}, Team{id:...} is responsible for Tag{qrcode:...}"; and again - you need to pay careful attention to "who gets to decide?"  The model? or the real world?